# How to `WriteVerbose`/`WriteDebug`/... from classes which don't inherit from `Cmdlet`

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to write a binary module for PowerShell. However I have a problem as I'd like to export common functionality into a helper method:

```
class Foo {
    Bar DoBaz() {
        if (bazzed) {
            WriteWarning(this.ToString() + " already bazzed");
            return baz;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

This of course doesn't work as `WriteVerbose` is a method of `Cmdlet`. I can pass it as lambda but this seems to be very roundabout way of doing it.

Comment: extension methods, maybe?

Comment: @vasily.sib I don't see how it would help I'm afraid (I'm not C# expert).

Comment: your common functions are used inside `Cmdlet`, right? So you can [read this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) and then use them just like you use any other `Cmdlet` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass the `Cmdlet` (or more commonly `PSCmdlet`) instance to the helper method.  Here's an example

```
using System.Management.Automation;

[Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "Cmdlet")]
public class TestCmdletCommand : PSCmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        HelperMethods.WriteFromHelper(this, "message");
    }
}

public static class HelperMethods
{
    public static void WriteFromHelper(PSCmdlet cmdlet, string message)
    {
        cmdlet.WriteVerbose(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: also, if you change `WriteFromHelper` definition to this: `public static void WriteFromHelper(this PSCmdlet cmdlet, string message)`, you will be able to call it from `ProcessRecord()` like this: `this.WriteFromHelper("message");`